# Storing a static mapping in Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I need to store a static mapping of classes which is known to me in advance.

Situation- I have bunch of styles and each style has its corresponding decorator. This mapping is known to me at compile time and I want to have this mapping stored somehow to query at runtime to load the appropriate decorator for a style. What is the best way to store such mapping?

Comment: Would a properties file do what you need?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this concept. Just read. Looks like yes. But is there any alternative construct (possibly using some design) by which we can achieve the same? One way I think is, have an enum to store these values side by side and query the enum and it iterates through and returns the value. Looks like property file would do IO and impact performance a little.

Comment: Are you thinking of this mapping as being part of your program?  Or is it something that you might want to change without having to recompile and redeploy your code?  If it really is part of your program, then an enum will work fine.  But if you want your operations staff to be able to change the mapping, without asking your development staff to create a new release, then a properties file is better.  With a properties file, you'd do the IO just once, when your program starts up, and then you'd have the mapping in memory from there, so you wouldn't really have a performance hit.

Comment: You are correct. In my use case change of mapping would be required only if there some change in code. Hence, recompilation and redeploy is inevitable. Looks like enum would be better for me as I want this mapping as part of my program.

Comment: OK.  Now, I'm not sure what you mean by "style" above.  If the keys to the mapping are actually the classes in your program, then the right way to do this is with annotations, as described in Kong's answer.  If the keys to the mapping are something different, you might consider just using a HashMap populated with some hardcoded values.

Comment: Keys(Styles) and Values(Decorators) both are classes. Kong's answer looks appropriate its just I'll need little more study.

Comment: If a properties file is even on the radar for your requirements then my answer is a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Simple is good. I thought you were building a full framework. A Factory pattern is another simple alternative.

Comment: I considered Factory pattern but looks like I had a lot of "instanceOf" check because of it. To avoid these instanceOf checks I thought of maintaining a static mapping to just lookup the correct type and instantiate the correct object.

Comment: Actually, @Kong, I like your solution now that I better understand the requirement.  I don't feel it's nuking the mosquito.  It would be fairly straightforward to factor out all the annotation processing into a single method like `public static Class<?> findDecoratorFor(Class<?> style)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could annotate your classes with a custom or JSR-250 annotation. Your framework code could then scan the class path to build up the relationships at runtime.

Spring uses this approach (as well as others) to define the dependencies at compile time and build up the context at runtime.

An example could be something like this:

```
@Decorator("MyDecorator")
public class MyStyle implements Style...
```

Spring also provides classes that make the whole scanning process much simpler, for example:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html

Comment: This looks fantastic and I would definitely need to explore these annotations how to.

Comment: Looked around a little to accommodate my use case but looks like it'll need much reading. If you could point me to an example which addresses a similar use case it would be great.

Comment: Done! I didn't accept initially because I was exploring to see if I could apply it to my use case. Thanks. :)